# Partial queries in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In Pandas one can do the following:

```
df.query("some_column in ('foo', 'bar')")
```

which retrieves the subset of `df` where the column `some_column` takes the value `'foo'` or `'bar'`.

But what if I want to do the opposite? For example, find the subset of `df` where any **substring** of the strings in the column `some_column` matches 'foo' or 'bar`.

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern).

```
df['some column'].str.contains(r'foo|bar')
```

For example:

```
In [8]: Series(['foo', 'bar', 'fo', 'foo2']).str.contains(r'foo|bar')
Out[8]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I do this so that the search is case insensitive?

Comment: Compile a regex pattern and pass that. Take a look at the regex docs.